# Javascript Fadein Fadeout text in <th><div> header cell

Tags: javascript

I have attempt several different ways to accomplish this and I can either get the fadeIn or fadeOut to work, but not both. What I am looking for is being able to click on the image stored in the a href attribute and fadeIn the word "Update" into the div id tag, fadeOut, then fadeIn the words "More Tools" or just show the words "More Tools" since it is already the value in the th header cell.

```
<a id="1" href="" class ="edit_button" title="edit1"><img src="images/editbutton.jpg" title="Submit Your Edit" border="0" height="24" width="24"></img></a>


<th colspan="3"><div id="editupdate">More Tools</div></th>


function (data) {
$('#editupdate').fadeIn().html('Update').delay(2500).fadeOut();
    });
```

Comment: The function I have posted is actually part of a much larger function the submits data to a php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following...

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dPY2P/2/)

```
    $("#editupdate").fadeIn(1000,function(){
        var tmp = $(this).html();
        $("#editupdate").html('Update').fadeOut(1500, function(){
            $("#editupdate").html(tmp).fadeIn(1500);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Nikhil - worked perfectly.  I really appreciated the fiddle. Helps folks like myself that do not have the skills yets...to see how everything works as a visual.  Thanks again. Kurt

Answer (score 0):

The reason that's not working is because the `html` function doesn't go into the fx queue used by `fadeIn`, `fadeOut`, and `delay`. To have code be in the queue, you can use the `queue` jQuery function. http://api.jquery.com/queue/#queue-queueName-callback-next-

```
$("#editupdate").fadeIn(1000).queue(function(next) {
    $(this).html("Update");
    next(); //make sure the next function in the queue gets triggered
}).delay(2500).fadeOut(1500);
```

That should do what it looks like your sample code is attempting to do. If you want to change the element's HTML again after the `fadeOut`, simply add another call to queue. Alternatively, you could use `fadeIn`'s callback argument to do the same thing (as suggested by Nikhil). I prefer this method because it avoids having functions inside functions, but they do the same thing.

Comment: Jeremy - thanks for the reply and the link. I will take a look at it. Thanks again, Kurt